# Referenceerror: cordova is not defined ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Firstly I created blank Project with

```
ionic start checkGPS blank
```

After that i installed plugin -

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

I added following code in www/index.html

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("GPS location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
})
```

Looking in config.xml & package.json
Plugin information is already added, even i tried adding `cordova.js`

But it didn't work though!

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
            console.log("GPS location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
            alert('hello');
        }, function(error){
            console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
        })
    }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I added...

Comment: You are sure that is not getting a 404 error in the line `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`? Please, inspect your app and check the console output.

Comment: Are you testing in a browser or in a real device?

Comment: No Error in console as i added cordova.js file.

Comment: @BrunoPeres I Tried on browser, emulator & real device as well

Comment: Your index.html file worked fine for me in a new project.

Comment: @BrunoPeres Please build it for android, and check as i am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem occurs because the device is not ready. Try adding your code in the [deviceready()](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) lifecycle event. Like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
        console.log("GPS location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    })
}, false);
```

Comment: Please, update your question with the complete index.html file.

Comment: Yes, Done please check